# What is the difference between at the cafe, in the cafe, and by the cafe?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

so I'm learing Norwegian now at Duolingo. My native languange is not English. So I confused about a sentence that means "We wait by the cafe." Why is it 'by the cafe', not 'in the cafe' or 'at the cafe'?

Comment: Why not? Do you know what "by" means? If so, please explain what about "by the cafe" confuses you?

Answer (score 2):

A café is a store which you can go inside of.

It is also a landmark which you can recognize and use as a reference point without going inside.

Each of the prepositions you use would be acceptable grammatically, but there are different meanings:

- "We wait **in** the café" means we go inside the café and wait. It is likely, but not guaranteed, that we order something to eat or drink; we might sit down at a table while we wait.
- "We wait **by** the café" means we wait *outside* it. It is simply a reference point, nothing more. You could also say "We wait by the mailbox" or "We wait by the fountain."
- "We wait **at** the café" can mean either of the above. I would say it is more likely to mean "by" than "in" but either is possible.